# How did my BigQuery bill get calculated

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been playing with Bigquery and building some aggregates for a reporting product. To my horror I noticed that my bill so far this month is over $4000! There doesn't seem to be any way of breaking down my usage - is there a report I can get of queries by data processed/cost?

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery data processing is billed at $0.035 per gigabyte. (see pricing [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing)). You can see how much data you're processing by looking at your query jobs.

If you're using the UI, it will tell you how much data your query processed next to the 'Run Query' button. If you're using the bq command-line tool, you can see the jobs you've run by running `bq ls -j` and then show how much data has been processed by each job by running `bq show -j job_0bb47924271b433b895b690726099f69` (substitute your own job id here). If you're running queries by using the API directly, the number of bytes scanned is returned on the job in the statistics.totalBytesProcessed field.

If you'd like to reduce the amount you're spending, you can either use fewer columns in your queries, break your tables up into smaller pieces (e.g. daily tables), or use the batch query mode for non-time-sensitive queries which is only $0.020/GB processed.

If you break tables into smaller pieces, you can always do queries over multiple tables when needed using the ',' syntax. E.g. `SELECT foo from table1, table2, table3`.